# Azure Data Studio, Docker, SQL Server - problem occurred while running the kernel

Tags: sql, azure, docker

> Could not start session: Notebook process exited
> prematurely with error code: 1

I am working with Azure Data Studio and want to create a new deployment using SQL Server Container Image. I am currently facing an issue while running the notebook " Run SQL Server 2019 container image with Docker". I am attaching the message I got from the kernel.

Thank you for your help in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuRr2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like permission issue. If the file is in System folder (for example User folder), you will face permission issue.

If you re-run the setup using your own user folder (like in %USERPROFILE%) the notebook should start successfully.